# regular expression python index:count

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, regex-greedy

I have list of values as string "index:count" I want to extract the index and count in the string as in the below code:

```
          string="358:6 1260:2 1533:7 1548:292 1550:48 1561:3 1564:186"
          values=[v for v in re.findall('.+?:.+?.', string)]
          for g in values:
              index=g[:g.index(":")]
              count=g[g.index(":")+1:]
              print(int(index)+" "+str(count))
```

But I got error message

> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '2 1550'

it seems I wrote the regular expression operations wrongly. any idea how to fix this?

Comment: or if you are using an updated python: `print(f"{index} {count}")`

Comment: Given it is just a standard separator, `print(index, count)` would also work and avoid `str` concat or `f-string` construction.

Comment: `print([chunk.split(':') for chunk in string.split()])`

Comment: Since you're already using a regex, why not use it to do the splitting too? Just `re.findall('(.+?):(.+?).', string)` will give you a list of (index, count) pairs.

Comment: The problem isn't the string printing, it's with the regex. Try putting your regex into a visualizer (e.g. regex101.com) to see what your regex actually matches

Comment: I think something like ^(.*?):[0-9] would be better

Comment: As a side note: `[v for v in …]` does the same thing as `list(…)` but a bit slower and more verbose. And in this case, (a) you've already got a list, and (b) you don't need a list anyway, just anything you can iterate with a `for` loop, so you don't need to do anything with the result of `findall` at all; just use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you won't need the `?` lazy modifier at the end of the regex pattern. The `?` lazy modifier you put there can actually produce more noise than capturing the right data

**EDIT NOTE:** the pattern `.+:.+` I introduced in previous edits was a wrong or even a bad regex pattern to capture the desired pattern. Please use the `\d+:\d+` pattern instead. However, I leave it be because it still can solve the OP's problem using another workaround.

As long as your data is not malformed or contain noise and is neatly separated with a whitespace, I think `'.+:.+'` is sufficient to find your `index:count` format. Probably the best way is to use `\d+:\d+` since you know it is at least one `digit` separated by a `:` and followed by another `digit`.

Here are good links [regexr](https://regexr.com/) and [regex101](https://regex101.com/) to better design/visualize your regex pattern.

If you use the `.+:.+` pattern, it will return you the string as a whole since it matches the string as a whole. You need to preprocess the result since [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall) returns a `list`, in this example, it returns only 1 element.

```
In [  ]: string="358:6 1260:2 1533:7 1548:292 1550:48 1561:3 1564:186"
    ...: values=[v for v in re.findall('.+:.+', string)]
    ...: print(values)
['358:6 1260:2 1533:7 1548:292 1550:48 1561:3 1564:186']
```

Since it returns a list with only one element, you can use [`pop()`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html) to take the only `str` element out and print it nicely with `str` function [`split()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.split).

```
In [  ]: print(values.pop().split())
['358:6', '1260:2', '1533:7', '1548:292', '1550:48', '1561:3', '1564:186']
```

If you are using `\d+:\d+` pattern, it will directly return you a nicely separated list since it correctly finds them. Therefore, you can directly print its value.

```
In [  ]: string="358:6 1260:2 1533:7 1548:292 1550:48 1561:3 1564:186"
    ...: values=[v for v in re.findall('\d+:\d+', string)]
    ...: print(values)
['358:6', '1260:2', '1533:7', '1548:292', '1550:48', '1561:3', '1564:186']
```

Finally, you can print the result nicely with built-in [string formatting](https://pyformat.info/). **Disclaimer:** I do not own that website, I just found it useful for beginner me :)

```
In [  ]: for s in values:
    ...:     index, count = s.split(":")
    ...:     print("Index: {:>8} Count: {:>8}".format(index, count))
    ...:     
Index:      358 Count:        6
Index:     1260 Count:        2
Index:     1533 Count:        7
Index:     1548 Count:      292
Index:     1550 Count:       48
Index:     1561 Count:        3
Index:     1564 Count:      186
```

Comment: It needs the lazy non greedy matching. Else it will match the first number till the : and then the whole rest of the string. The \d+:\d+ works because whitespaces are not \d-matches - it will eventually lead to the same results as his lazy grouping contstruct. btw. http://regex101.com has a python specific mode, which regexr has not (I change to http://regex101.com for that exact reason). You also use regex AND string.split() - why? findall already can deliver you tuples by using capturing groups - no need to split again afterwards.

Comment: @PatrickArtner, I personally won't use the greedy non-greedy matching because I knew that `re.find_all` returns `list` in OP's desired format. Thanks for letting me know about regex101.com! I found regexr sometimes need some tweaks before I can roll it into my python script. Yes, I was wrong in introducing the `.+:.+` pattern so I put an edit notes just above it to not use that pattern because it was **WRONG**. It's almost dawn in Asia, it's probably because my brain is almost out ;P

Comment: Btw @PatrickArtner, I tried the OP's regex pattern `.+?:.+?` in the regexr.com and found that it doesn't actually capture well. I also tried it in python and it sometimes returns `2 1550 48`. That's why I introduced another pattern using `\d` coupled with `re.find_all` instead and introduced string formatting

Comment: yep ... after I provided the same pattern (with groups) about 30mins earlier ;)  yours is a nice answer non the less and got my +1

Comment: Thanks Patrick! :) mission accomplished, heading straight to bed now

Comment: Perfect explanation. Thanks a lot it worked like a charm :)

Answer (score 3):

You are already using regex - why not simply use groupings and create a dict from it?

```
import re

s="358:6 1260:2 1533:7 1548:292 1550:48 1561:3 1564:186"

values= dict(re.findall('(\d+):(\d+) ?', s)) # use capturing groups

for g in values:
    print(g, values[g])
```

Output:

```
 358 6
1260 2
1533 7
1548 292
1550 48
1561 3
```

You have your key/value pairs conveniently inside a dictionary (all as strings).
You are loosing your ordering by that, but for key/values that should be no problem.

If you need this ordering, just use the returned list of findall:

```
values = re.findall('(\d+):(\d+) ?', s) # use capturing groups
```

which gives you a list of tuples with your matches returned:

```
[('358', '6'), ('1260', '2'), ('1533', '7'), ('1548', '292'),
 ('1550', '48'), ('1561', '3'), ('1564', '186')]
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to concat string and int.

Replace

```
print(int(index)+" "+str(count))
```

With

```
print(str(index)+" "+str(count))
```

*You can also simplify your code.*

**Ex:**

```
import re
string="358:6 1260:2 1533:7 1548:292 1550:48 1561:3 1564:186"
values=[v for v in re.findall('.+?:.+?.', string)]
for g in values:
  index, count =g.split(":")
  print(index, count)
```

Comment: Both `index` and `count` are already `str` - `print(index + " " + count)` is sufficient. To really simplify `print(index, count)` would also be sufficient.